# Webpack large bundle size with duplicate modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app, react-pdf

I see a huge increase in bundle size in my react app, and there are 13 bundles, each one about 3Mb, and they all share react-pdf and material-ui. I have no idea how to solve this, the app works but I am concerned.

**source-map-explorer output** :

[image: source-map-explorer output]

Here is my package.json file,[package.json](https://github.com/adamfarmer0/problems/blob/master/package.json)

If you can point me in the right direction on how to solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

Webpack-bundle-analyzer output:
[bundle-analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI4rn.png)

Comment: https://formidable.com/blog/2018/finding-webpack-duplicates-with-inspectpack-plugin/

Comment: Unfortunately, I made this project using create-react-app so I don't have a webpack.config file, I kind of solved the problem by going back to a previous commit - thanks github-. It seems like after I ran code cleanup tool and changed lots of code in Webstorm IDE, it broke some stuff since after that commit build size increased 4 times.

Comment: `source-map-explorer` is not actually a great tool to do this, I built a [script](https://gist.github.com/HamidOsouli/5a79294665fbacc9826066596863d214) to use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` with `CRA` and I highly recommend you to use it and then share the output.

Comment: I ran your script and added it to the post. It shows lots of material-ui datagrid module, this is after I "fixed" the problem btw, its gzipped 3mb, parsed 11mb, stat 20mb.

Comment: I updated all the packages with ncu -u, updated lots of code to make it work with the new versions, now I don't have any duplicate material ui chunks. its gzipped 1.6mb, parsed 6.17mb, stat 13.31mb. Can you please check if there is any problem with this? I am very inexperienced with this stuff. https://i.imgur.com/EW6PYMq.png